# Error converting datatype numeric to decimal

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I have a database column defined as `amount decimal (19, 9)`.

In the UI it is a free text where user can enter value, whatever user enters value after that internally it gets multiplied by 1000.

Now when I am trying to save it to database, I get an error

> Error converting datatype numeric to decimal

If I entered value as `78654323`, now internally it gets multiplied by thousand

```
78654323 * 1000 = 78654323000
```

and on save I get this error. Why ?

What validation/data annotation should I put on the textbox for the range ?

Comment: because the meaning of decimal(19, 9) is 10 place number digits and 9 decimal place digits. 78654323000 exceeds the value 9999999999. 999999999

Comment: ok. What validation should i put on textbox ?

Comment: use range validation and accept values from 0 to 9999999 only.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** this is for SQL Server (you haven't said so - but it looks like it):

You have defined your `amount` column to be of type `decimal(19,9)` in the database. You're **not** getting 19 digits before and 9 digits after the decimal point (which is what a lot of programmer's seem to think this notation means).

What is really means is:

- you get a **total** of 19 digits
- of that, there are **9 digits** after the decimal point

and thus you get **10 digits** *before* the decimal point.

When multiplying your entered value of `78654323` by one thousand, you end up with a value `78654323000` which has **11 digits** (before the decimal point), and thus you **cannot** safe this value.

You need to increase the number of available digits before the decimal point (by using e.g. `decimal(25,9)` giving you 16 digits before the decimal point).

Answer (score 0):

Your validation should be like getting total of 19 digits after multiplication with 1000. It should not cross 19(total before & after decimal) digits. It needs some calculation work on it. based on the result we should provide the validation.

For your result when it goes to database it will be stored as : 78654323000.00000000 which is suitable for decimal(20,9) not for decimal(19,9). so, 1 digit at before decimal should not be after multiplication.